# Why does using Cytoscape I can`t align text correcnly

Tags: cytoscape.js

I am vizualizing my db with cytoscape.js, but I can't align the parent nodes text correctly *(by object)*. It seems like the "parent" selector does not exist. All other selectors are working correctly for me.

Here is the important part of my js file:

```
var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById('cy'),
  style: [{
      selector: 'node',
      css: {
        'content': 'data(label)',
        'text-valign': 'center',
        'text-halign': 'center',
        'font-style': 'oblique',
        'font-size': 10,
        'shape': 'round-rectangle',
      }
    },
    {
      selector: 'parent',
      css: {
        'text-valign': 'top',
        'text-halign': 'center',
        'font-style': 'normal',
        'font-size': 15,
      }
    },
    {
      selector: 'edge',
      css: {
        'curve-style': 'unbundled-bezier',
        'control-point-distances': [-20, 10],
        'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle'
      }
    }
  ],

  elements: myElements,

  layout: {
    name: 'preset',
    padding: 5
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the parent selector wrong, you can read up on these selectors in the [docs](https://js.cytoscape.org/#selectors/state):

```
var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById('cy'),
  style: [{
      selector: 'node',
      css: {
        'content': 'data(label)',
        'text-valign': 'center',
        'text-halign': 'center',
        'font-style': 'oblique',
        'font-size': 10,
        'shape': 'round-rectangle',
      }
    },
    {
      selector: ':parent',
      css: {
        'text-valign': 'top',
        'text-halign': 'center',
        'font-style': 'normal',
        'font-size': 15,
      }
    },
    {
      selector: 'edge',
      css: {
        'curve-style': 'unbundled-bezier',
        'control-point-distances': [-20, 10],
        'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle'
      }
    }
  ],

  elements: myElements,

  layout: {
    name: 'preset',
    padding: 5
  }
});
```

Comment: If this answers your question, please accept it with the check mark. That way, people searching for the same answer can find it more easily.